# Using Time comparison in Excel

Tags: excel, time, comparison

I am trying to compare current time with an employees available time to change the color of a cell to show employees current availability status.  What I'm looking for is if employee A is available on Jan. 1 from 6:00AM to 6:00PM.  I want to display a green cell if the current time falls during employee A's availability.  Please help.  I have tried comparing NOW() with TIMEVALUE, but have not had much luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula in conditional formatting:

```
=(NOW()>=B1)*(NOW()<=C1)
```

[image]